# HAN ValueError: Unknown layer: AttentionWithContext in getting deep copy of model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, attention-model

I am fitting HAN model in my data. And Want to save all the models in each iteration. For this purpose I am making a list of model at each iteration. And getting following error while deep copying the model.

```
ValueError: Unknown layer: AttentionWithContext
```

I have tried clone_model and different ways to get copy of model but get the same error

```
models_list.append(copy.deepcopy(model))
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using to build the model which will give more context to understand your problem. Also please refer to the following question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218234/not-able-to-load-keras-trained-model) and let me know if it helps!